# How to ensure that async methods are executed before using their returned result?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I have AsyncService class which contains two async methods.

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {
    @Async
    public HashMap<int, Student> studentMap(List<String> students) {
        //contains database call
        return result1;
    }

    @Async
    public HashMap<int, Teacher> teacherMap(List<String> teachers) {
        //contains database call
        return result2;
    }
}
```

Those two methods are called from UserService class.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public List<User> doJob () {
        HashMap<int, Student> = asyncService.studentMap(students);
        HashMap<int, Teacher> = asyncService.teacherMap(teachers);
        // now work with these HashMap
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that when I am using the returned result from those two  async calls, the two async methods are done. How can i do that? I know completable future can be a solution here. But i am not sure how to use it here. Is there any other solution? I am using spring boot.

Comment: If you expect the result to be ready, you basically want to behave them synchronously. Why use async then?

Comment: Method will not wait for result of async method,for that you have to user sync method.

Comment: @Henry, Those are long database calls. So I want to execute those in parallel. Synchronous call is making the API slower.

Comment: I really hope you don't have a class called `Hashmap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. That was a silly mistake.

Comment: This is covered by the official Spring guide about async methods: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `CompletableFuture`. Here is an example:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
                       asyncService.studentMap(students);//make it synchronized call
                ),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
                       asyncService.teacherMap(teachers);// make it synchronized call
        ).thenRun(() -> {
            //do after complete 2 async call.
        }).get();
```

Your service call need to sync:

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {
public Hashmap<int, Student> studentMap(List<String> students) {
    //contains database call
    return result1;
}

public Hashmap<int, Teacher> teacherMap(List<String> teachers) {
    //contains database call
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Async` annotation supposes the annotated method returns `Future`. Having  a `Future` you just has no other way to use the result except to invoke `Future.get()` which returs strictly after the async procedure is done.
That is, implement the asynchronous service correctly and you have no troubles.